# VideoSurface.mAdjustTransform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, agora.io

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHFr0.png)

Hey Guys!
I am using Agora.io for video chat intigration but I am having issue with VideoSurface Script (I got this script with in the Agora plugin)
I cant find ( madjusttransform ) in VideoSurface Script
Kindly help me out !

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: and well ... in the [API](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/unity/v2.9.1/class_video_surface.html) there is no `madjusttransform` mentioned anyway so why do you think it is there?

Comment: do you maybe mean `public SetTransformDelegate mAdjustTransfrom` ?? You know that case matters in c#? I vote to close this question as **typo-based**

Answer (score 0):

you must be following a dated tutorial.  Can you let us know which one that was? In short, yep, no worries about mAdjustTransfrom.